# How can I deactivate touch beeps during video recording?

Tags: iphone, video-capture

iPhone XS records touch beeps during video capture - every I tap on the scrren (f.e. zoom button x1/x2) result as an annoying beep sound in the recorded video. Even the final tap on Stop button is recorded.

Important: there are NO beeps when I touch the screen. This is not acoustic recording of environmental sounds.

Is it a feature that I can deactivate or is it a defect?

Here link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=353AS4MQNEU

(strangely, the beep sound when watching on mobile is significantly louder than on PC)

iOS 16.4.1

Comment: Simply disable Microphone for screen recording? Or maybe try enabling Silent Mode.

Comment: @Thinkr this is not screen recording. And there are no beeps when i touch the screen during the recording, the beeps are only on the videos.